# Continuing the 'for' where you left off

Tags: delphi

The code below goes through the entire contents of `Memo1`, and exit when `Label2 = Edit1`. So far so good, I would like to know how I do so when I click `Button1` again after the exit, it continues from the line below `Memo1` and not from the beginning again.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
 for i := 0 to Memo1.Lines.Count - 1 do
 begin
  Label2.Caption := Memo1.Lines.Strings[i];
  Sleep(2500);

  if Trim(Label2.Caption) = (Edit1.Text) then
   begin
    messageBeep(0);
    exit;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: You can remember current counter in some global variable (class field) and start for loop from that value. But in general this approach looks weird. What real problem you are going to solve?

Comment: you need a `conditional loop`but are using an `unconditional loop` . Why ? Use a `while` loop and this can be done a lot easier

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare a variable in your form class named `FCurrentLine` of type `Integer`
2. Change your loop to read `for i := FCurrentLine to ...`
3. When you exit the loop set `FCurrentLine := i + 1`